# Allowing users to see a sub-site exists but not to access

Tags: search, permissions, content

I have a simple site collection at the moment, one main home site with a sub-site for each active project.

I've added everyone to the visitors group which gives them read access to the home site. The sub-site (a project) is restricted to only members of the sub-site group.

But - I am using a content search to pull details of the active project (logo, title and sub-heading) onto the main home site. Think of a 3 x 3 grid with all active projects in it. A user can then click through each one to see the detail.

I think the current permissions are working a little too well in that the project sub-site is not being shown in the content search for a visitor.

How can I show the page in the content search but not allow them to click through and visit the site?

Comment: Since you said they can click through to see the detail, it sounds like you want them to have access to the projects list but not the rest of the site. Is that correct?

Comment: Currently no projects show on the home page grid because normal users don't have view, read or edit access to the project pages. I want them to be able to see the project exists, but to get a request access message if they try to click on the project link.

Comment: You said "A user can then click through each one to see the detail." What did you mean by that?

Comment: Hi Erin, what I think I should have said is that a user with the correct permissions is able to click through each one to see the detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the project list from the subsite to the top site and have a link to the subsite. If they can read the list they can see the data in the list even tho they cannot access the subsite.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I have done for now. Instead of using a Content Search query I have simply created a static table. I don't know if it is possible to show information via a content search query that the user does not have permission to see, as that would seem to go against the idea of permissions!

Comment: You cannot. The only way to use search is to grant users access to the content you want to see in search. BTW, you can still use Content Query (or CBS) if you like the looks of that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone will have a better solution, but for me I would create a simple SharePoint Group in your subsite, with few permissions (just for example "enumerate permissions") granted for all authenticated users. And after a full crawl see if it works.

Comment: Thanks - I think that would work however I can't seem to select "enumerate permissions" without it auto-selecting "view page". I want the Content Search to return information to the home page (logo, title and description) but for all other information (including the page view) to be inaccessible to the site collection visitors.